# Order of Maven subprojects in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Is it possible to set the order of Maven subproject's view in Netbeans?
I mean this :

- I have a top project and subprojects :

[image]

As you see, the project "tfomsRegistryParent" is a top level project, and other projects are modules of this project.

I tried to set the `<name>` in each module and in top level project, so it works, but I don't know whether it is a good solution or not:

[image]

Can I set any property in Netbeans to show my toplevel project in the top of the project's tree? I am using Netbeans version 8.1.